# jQuery get data attribute on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that will append to **two** places on my web application. One is a list item and the other is a hidden field on a HTML form (which I process the data in a PHP service file).

However, I want that if a user clicks the 'x' icon that all the elements are removed that have the same ID.

I have a good idea how to do this but my script below doesn't even log the ID. The `.control` block is giving me the issue. The `#add` code block successfully appends the HTML.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    // RENDER LIST
    var playerList = ""; //
    playerList += "<li class='selection'>" + $("#player").val() + "<i class='fa fa-close control' data-id='" + $("#playerGUID").val() + "'> </i>" + "</li>";

    $(playerList).appendTo("#playerList");

    // ADD GUID TO SUBMISSION VALUES
    var playerHTML = "";
    playerHTML += "<input data-id='" + $("#playerGUID").val() + "' type='hidden' name='playerGUID[]' value='" + $("#playerGUID").val() + "' />";

    $(playerHTML).appendTo("#selected-players");

    // CLEAR INPUT FIELD
    $("#player").val('');
});

$(".control").click(function() {
    $targetID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("Selected ID:" + $targetID);

    // REMOVE WILL COME HERE
});
```

Comment: _`all the elements are removed that have the same ID`_?? `ID` have to be unique per page...

Comment: If you're using bad/broken code on purpose, you can't expect it to work properly. As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sd6Lbydc/), in case of more than one element having the same ID, jQuery will just take the first.

Comment: Could you please post some of your HTML code?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I had the exact same reaction reading this sentence. As in "Don't tell me you did what I think you did..."

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ID in this case is just a HTML5 data attribute. They are fine to have the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".control")` doesn't exist at the time you bind the click event. You will need to delegate the event like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".control", function() {
    $targetID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("Selected ID:" + $targetID);
   // REMOVE WILL COME HERE
});
```

What happens here is that jQuery will bind a listener on the document (which always exists) rather than the `.control` which will not exist until you create it via a click to the `#add`. That way if can catch events on elements with class `control` even if the elements themselves were added later.

Check [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) under *Direct and delegated events* for more details.

**Note:** Instead of using `$(document)` you can bind the event on any element which will be a parent of `.control` and is available when you bind the event (e.g. `body`). Ideally you'd want to bind it to the closest parent element which is present when the document is loaded.

Comment: Ahh that's perfect! Thanks for the explanation. It makes perfect sense. =] will tick sooon enough! I guess I like to have all my `.click()` functions looking uniform so I didn't consider this.

Comment: Your description of how delegated event bindings work is correct, however, I would advise not always falling back to `document` as the top listener -- there is less overhead in using the first parent of the target control that will always exist, a `div` or something of that nature.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ thanks for the comment, I've added it as a note. The only reason I used the document was because I didn't know the structure of the page here.

Comment: @apokryfos: Fair enough. It looks like in this case that maybe `#selected-players` would work.

Comment: You're both right - I shrinked down the range of the parent and went for the closet container.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.on` bind event instead of `.click`

```
$(".control").on("click",function() {
    $targetID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("Selected ID:" + $targetID);

    // REMOVE WILL COME HERE
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click()` binding you're using is called a direct binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exists. It won't get bound to elements created later. To do that, You'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Eg.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="playerList">playerList</div>

        <div id="selected-players">selected-players</div>

        <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#add").click(function() {

            // RENDER LIST
            var playerList = ""; //
            playerList += "<li class='selection'>Dynamic LI " + $("#player").val() + "<i class='fa fa-close control' data-id='sample-data-id " + $("#playerGUID").val() + "'> <b>iVal-Click Here</b> </i>" + "</li>";

            $(playerList).appendTo("#playerList");

            // ADD GUID TO SUBMISSION VALUES
            var playerHTML = "";
            playerHTML += "<input data-id='" + $("#playerGUID").val() + "' type='hidden' name='playerGUID[]' value='" + $("#playerGUID").val() + "' />";

            $(playerHTML).appendTo("#selected-players");

            // CLEAR INPUT FIELD
            $("#player").val('');
        });

        $("#playerList").on("click", ".control", function() {
            $targetID = $(this).attr('data-id');
            console.log("Selected ID:" + $targetID);

            // REMOVE WILL COME HERE
        });

        });

    </script>   

    </body>
    </html>
```